# scrapy only save one item

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I have a question about save list item one by one in scrapy

My code is like this :

```
class MySpider(Spider): 
    name = "test"
    start_urls=[""]
    def parse(self, response):
        sel =  Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.html')]")   #many .html
        for i,site in enumerate(sites):
            item = YoutoItem()             
            item['link'] = site.xpath("./@href").extract()[0]
            item['title'] = site.xpath("./text()").extract()[0]
            yield Request(url=link,meta={'item':item}, callback=self.parse_ler)
            break #just test the first one.html

    def parse_ler(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        sel =  Selector(response)
        url = sel.xpath("//embed/@src").extract()
        for t in url:
            print t  #it will print url1,url2,url3
            item['url'] = t
            yield item
```

And My pipline.py

```
class YoutoPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item.save()
        return item
```

And the terminal will printout:

```
{'link': u'http://test.html',
 'title': u'A',
 'url': u'url1'}
{'link': u'http://test.html',
 'title': u'A',
 'url': u'url2'}
{'link': u'http://test.html',
 'title': u'A',
 'url': u'url3'}
```

But when it save to database , it will ony saved one of them

```
 {'link': u'http://test.html',
 'title': u'A',
 'url': u'url1'}
```

I thinl it's because item['url'] is get by forloop

Please teach me how to edit to save these 3 datas seperately into database
My database is postgreSQL

**EDIT**:

I found a method : 
just put the item = YoutoItem() under the forloop
And It can work:

```
for t in url:
    item = YoutoItem()    
    item['url'] = t
    yield item
```

Comment: How is parse_ler called? What are you doing with the dictionary item you yield in that function?

Comment: the title A is an activity,it has 3 films(url1,url2,url3),I want to save it to database.

Comment: @user2492364 Show us code about invoking function parse_ler to insert data into database so that we can know why only first one is saved.

Comment: I found a way .put ````item = YoutoItem()````  under the ````for t in url```` and it can work

Comment: hold on, in this case you don't need to pass **item** in `request.meta` as the *items* are totally different objects

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the items separately in database, just use another `YoutoItem()`

```
yield Request(url=link,meta={'item':item}, callback=self.parse_ler)
```

can be rewritten to:

```
# def parse
# or Request if you import scrapy.Request, and you don't need request.meta
yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_ler)
```

---

```
# def parse_ler, which you don't need the request.meta anymore
sel =  Selector(response)
url = sel.xpath("//embed/@src").extract()
for t in url:
    item = YoutiItem() # just construct a new YoutoItem
    item['url'] = t
    yield item
```

Comment: thanks,but I need to save it seperately.And I found a method.Still thank you,I can use this skill next time!

Comment: @user2492364, ok, not knowing you need them separately, yes just use another scrapy item on parse2 will just work, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try disable the filter request like in this example:

```
Request(url=u, callback=self.parse_ler, meta={"item": item}, dont_filter = True)
```